# Get URLs from a website that uses javascript href and doesn't change URL

Tags: javascript, url, href

I'm trying to get the urls of the real estates on this page which **doesn't change the url** while navigating in that listing:

https://matrix.crmls.org/Matrix/Public/Portal.aspx?p=DE-662281912-340&k=8722994X129K&eml=cHN1bGludXhAZ21haWwuY29tt

I don't understand much about javascript but I know that for each real estate in that list there is a javascript `href`, for example the first one there has this `href`:
`href="javascript:__doPostBack('_ctl0$m_DisplayCore','Redisplay|373,,0')"`

What I'm trying to do is to get a unique `href` for each real estate on that list, I know that the community appreciates some who tries, but I really couldn't do anything here, I thought about maybe executing the javascript from the url but I don't know if that's possible, tried to check the network tab on chrome developer mode, and I didn't see anything that may help on this.

Thanks a lot for passing through!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but all links with this type of href can be collected by `document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="javascript:__doPostBack("]')` (see [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)).

Comment: @vsemozhebuty thanks a lot for your reply, and I'm sorry for not being very clear, but what I need very simply, is a URL that when I put in the url bar and hit enter, it should take me to see **one** real estate from that list I shared (url in the question).
So it's about how to have a url for each real estate in that list